# Using Prometheus, How to use the selected period of time in a query for getting Grafana's data?

Tags: python, api, prometheus, grafana, promql

I'm using Grafana with Prometheus and I'd like to build a query that depends on the selected period of time selected in the upper right corner of the screen.

Is there any variable (or something like that) to use in the query field?

In other words, If I select 3hrs I'd like to use that data in the query. Using that query I will get the data in between that specified timeframe. How can I build a query to get a values with the total number of requests during a period of time (for example:3hrs)?

currently I am executing on particular time but I need to generate Excel report(output) for particular timeframe(for eg. 20-02-2023 6:00:00 to 20-02-2023 9:00:00) for that purpose, I have to use this query in python script and want to get timeframe data through Prometheus Query. Is that any way to find that query for particular Timeframe.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? How time range selected in Grafana's ui is related to your python script, that queries Prometheus?

Comment: In Grafana dashboard, when we want to get the data for particular timeframe then we can select the time on right upper corner. likewise, using prometheus query how can we get Grafana's data for particular timeframe (Example 3Hrs). which query I have to use for getting previous 3hrs data for mqtt n remaining all?

Answer (score 0):

It is extremely hard to understand what exactly you are looking for, so I will try a couple of guesses:

If you are looking for how to reference time range selected for Grafana dashboard in Prometheus' query: use variable [`$__range`](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/variables/add-template-variables/#__range). For example `metric offset $__range` in your example will show values from time range: `now-6h`, `now-3h`.

If you are looking for how to get data for specified range through Prometheus' API: use endpoint `api/v1/query_range` with query parameters `start` and `end`. For example:

```
curl -s 'https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/api/v1/query_range' \
  -d 'query=node_cpu_seconds_total' \
  -d 'start=2023-04-01T06:00:00Z' \
  -d end='2023-04-02T06:00:00Z' \
  -d step=1m
```

will get you `node_cpu_seconds_total` metric for period between `2023-04-01T06:00:00` and `2023-04-02T06:00:00` with resolution of one minute.